# WP + Superfish: Child menu item has hover/active applied when on parent page

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, drop-down-menu, superfish

The site: http://coqinn.lexcorp.ca/rooms-and-suites/

Hover over the Rooms & Suites menu item and you'll see what I mean, I need to make it stop doing this. It's not a major concern if the appropriate sub-menu item shows which is active, but I would like the primary menu item, even if it's a parent, to appear properly.

Sorry if my explanation of anything was poor, running on very little sleep. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the classes applied to that menu are only these:

```
class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"
```

Comment: I know it's this line that is messing it up, just not sure how to fix it:
`nav ul li a.active, nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li.current-menu-item a, nav ul li.current_page_item a, nav ul li.current-page-parent a {
 background: url("images/nav-hover.png") repeat-x scroll center top transparent;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #590407;
}`

Comment: After messing around with this a bit more I found a solution: `nav ul li.current-menu-item li a, nav ul li.current_page_item li a, nav ul li.current-page-parent li a {
 background:none !important;
}` .. thanks for the help. :)